# Rust: How to pass a mutable as immutable to a function

Tags: rust

I have a big function and it is seemingly difficult to implement in Rust. I am having trouble with Borrow checker and I searched StackOverflow and Google but not able to find an answer. This might be a duplicate but no solution worked for me

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn add(my: &mut MyStruct) {
    let count = my.count.entry("Test".to_string()).or_insert(1.0);
    let value = get_custom_val(my, 5.0);
    my.final_count = *count / value;
    *count = 5.0;
}

fn get_custom_val(my: &MyStruct, offset: f32) -> f32 {
    return my.val + offset;
}

struct MyStruct {
    count: HashMap<String,f32>,
    val: f32,
    final_count: f32
}

fn main() {
    let mut my = MyStruct {count: HashMap::new(), val: 1.0, final_count: 5.0};
    my.count.insert("Test".to_string(), 5.0);
    add(&mut my);
}
```

This is a very simple code here. But MyStruct in real has lot of HashMaps which has entry around 1000 elements. So I want to things more optimised.

With this error I get,

> cannot borrow `*my` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

It looks like a very basic manupulation and I am not able to achieve. I have been learning Rust for over a week and not able to quite understand this borrow :(

Can someone help me?

Some ideas were to add {} in `let value...` but that doesn't serve me because I need the value in next line.

Also, when I tried different thing (like changing `get_custom_val` to have `&mut`, I get below error

> cannot borrow `*my` as mutable more than once at a time

Comment: There's [no error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e3e18d039e25563e2b79e46e717cdd4e) in the code you posted. The error is elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry. I figured it now only. Playground is really useful for this. I have updated the code which throws error

Comment: In my case the count is an Vec of 50+ elements and I cant change the orders. I have just mentioned f32 here

Comment: swap first and second lines of the `add` function.

Answer (score 3):

Your add function should be (note how the first two lines are swapped):

```rust
fn add(my: &mut MyStruct) {
    let value = get_custom_val(my, 5.0);
    let count = my.count.entry("Test".to_string()).or_insert(1.0);
    my.final_count = *count / value;
    *count = 5.0;
}
```

Let's see why your old function errors:

```rust
fn add(my: &mut MyStruct) {
    // you get an Entry for the hashmap which requires a mutable reference to it
    let count = my.count.entry("Test".to_string()).or_insert(1.0);
    // the mutable reference is still there for the entry
    // but this function requires an immutable reference
    let value = get_custom_val(my, 5.0);
    // the error is thrown on this line because you try to use that mutable reference
    my.final_count = *count / value;
    *count = 5.0;
}
```